# cscope-index-files always shows "No match"

Tags: emacs, cscope

I've installed cscope and using xcscope.el in emacs.

I want to index my files in Emacs with `cscope-index-files`. But when setting the directory, it always says `No match`.

Answer (score 0):

The `cscope-index-files` command expects the user to provide a valid directory via the minibuffer, when invoked interactively. You can tell from the source code, in `xcscope.el`, by the first character of the string provided to the `interactive` function, in this case "D" which means directory:

```
(defun cscope-index-files (top-directory)
  (interactive "DIndex files in directory: ")
...
```

When I run `M-x cscope-index-files`, I see emacs say `No match` if I provide a directory that doesn't exist e.g. `~/aaaaa`; in this case emacs will not accept it, and the minibuffer displays `~/aaaaa[No match]`. Are you providing a valid directory when you invoke `cscope-index-files`?

Graham